# Is it possible to control the electron interference of a double-slits experiment by using electromagnetic lens?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

As we knew, people can focus or defocus the interference pattern of a photon-based double-slits experiment by using an optical lens. Actually, there are some groups using these to do quantum tomography.
Is it possible to control the electron interference of a double-slits experiment by using an electromagnetic lens?

Comment: That occurs all the time in electron microscopes...

Comment: I know that electromagnetic lens is a well-developed technique in electronic optics such as SEM, TEM or FIB. However, has it ever been used to control the convergence of interference after electrons passed through the slits?  Or more precisely, for quantum tomography?

Comment: In a TEM you vary the lenses past the sample which determine if the real space image or diffraction space image are projected onto the viewing screen or camera. So, yes, you certainly use the lenses to focus the diffraction pattern. Not quantum tomography per se though.